# Marshmallow-sqlalchemy: How to load all fields into schema from model which loads fields from database directly?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, marshmallow-sqlalchemy

I have this schema:

```py
class Users(SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Users
        include_fk = True
        include_relationships = True
```

The model is:

```py
class Users(db.Model):
    __table__ = db.Model.metadata.tables['dbo.Users']
```

As you can see, columns are set directly from table, and if I print columns from model, all columns are loaded, but if i print the schema, it is just an empty dict. I don't know how to load all fields without set them manually.

According to [marshmallow-sqlalchemy documentation](https://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html):

> *Any **column_property** on the model that does not derive directly from **Column** (such as a mapped expression), will be detected and marked as **dump_only**. **Hybrid_property** is not automatically handled at all, and would need to be explicitly declared as a field.*

But I don't know what it means exactly. I tried using `fields = '__all__'` but it throws the error: `ValueError: fields option must be a list or tuple.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was set fields from model's columns:

```py
class Users(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Users
        include_fk = True
        fields = models.Users.__table__.columns.keys() # This is the solution
```